# Brute force selection sort

Tags: r, brute-force, selection-sort

I am trying to write R code to do the Brute Force Selection Sort. But I dont know how to write the min<- i and min<-j part.

```
example <- function(x)

{

  for (i in 1:(length(x)-1))

  {

    #min <- i

    for (j in (i+1):(length(x)))

    {

      if (x[j] < x[(which.min(x))])

      {

        #min <- j

      }

    temp <- x[which.min(x)]

    x[which.min(x)] <- x[i]

    x[i] <- temp

    }

  }

  x

}

x <-sample(1:100,10)

example(x)
```

Can anyone help me finish the '#' Part?

I have also attached the pseudocode
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `min` is the index of the next minimum element.  So, it is the same as using `which.min` without the inner loop.

```
example <- function(x) {
  for (i in 1:(length(x)-1)) {
    mindex <- i  # or, mindex <- which.min(x[(i+1):length(x)]) and remove the next loop

    for (j in (i+1):(length(x))) {
      if (x[j] < x[mindex]) 
        mindex <- j
    }

    ## swap
    temp <- x[i]
    x[i] <- x[mindex]
    x[mindex] <- temp
  }
  x
}
```